# There are three cups of water. Can I just call them "the water"?

Tags: definite-article, discourse-context

There are three cups of water.

Can I just call them "the water"?

For example, "hey don't touch the water!"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if it is clear from context that you are talking about the cups. In some contexts this might be understood to mean "you can touch the cups, but not the contents". There may be better ways to communicate, again depending on context.